# What is an indicator column / multi-hot representation of a categorical column?

Tags: categorical-data, data-transformation, tensorflow, categorical-encoding

While looking into the TensorFlow documentation I came across the [indicator_column](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/indicator_column) described as

> Represents multi-hot representation of given categorical column.

I haven't been able to find anything by googling these terms. The example in the documentation looks like it is really just a simple count:

```
dense_tensor == [[1, 0, 0]]  # If "name" bytes_list is ["bob"]
dense_tensor == [[1, 0, 1]]  # If "name" bytes_list is ["bob", "wanda"]
dense_tensor == [[2, 0, 0]]  # If "name" bytes_list is ["bob", "bob"]
```

Is it just a count or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert but from the looks of it, yes it looks like a simple count. However I believe the intention is to have a class that can generate a multi-hot representation that wraps around any categorical_column_* kind of column according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/indicator_column). There is also a paragraph about the indicator_column in [the Wide & Deep tf tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep). It feels like it is a convenience class so that you don't have to write code to generate the representation yourself.